# SQL colum not found while in database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Today I encountered a very weird error.

My error:

> Column 'naam' not found.

Here is my query:

```
 ResultSet rs1 = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT titel from leningen where naam='" + username + "'");
```

Here you can see the database has the table:
[image]

Why is it telling me "Naam" not found? It should show "hallo" in my table view but because of this I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my full code as a reverence:

```
public void showboeken() throws IOException, SQLException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("showboeken.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 400);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("New Window");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\thomasmoed\\IdeaProjects\\bibliotheek\\save.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String username = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(username);

    try {
        System.out.println("Loading");
        columBoek.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("naam"));
    } catch (Exception lol) {
        System.out.println(lol);
    }

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bibliotheek?user=root");
        Connection con = conn;

        ResultSet rs1 = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT titel from leningen where naam='" + username + "'");

        ObservableList<UserModel> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        while (rs1.next()) {
            UserModel usr = new UserModel();
            usr.setNaam(rs1.getString("naam"));
            data.add(usr);
        }

        tableBoekenlening.setItems(data);
        UserModel item = tableBoekenlening.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(item.getNaam());
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlf) {
        System.out.println(sqlf.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I saw your answer and gave you +1 :)

Comment: suppose some important information is in exception message

Comment: concatenation not only exposes for hackers, but make problems for programmers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to run `rs1.getString("naam")`, you need to include `naam` among the columns you select.  Currently, you're just selecting `titel`.  So your SQL statement should probably be

```
"SELECT naam, titel FROM leningen WHERE naam='" + username + "'"
```

Also, be aware that constructing an SQL statement by concatenation like this leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.  I strongly recommend learning how to use prepared statements instead of using this approach.

Comment: Why does my query work in PHPmyadmin but not in Java? Your query works thank you

Comment: The query _does_ work in the form you first gave it, and returns a bunch of `titel` data.  The issue is that you were trying to retrieve a column called `naam` from a query that didn't have a column called `naam`.

Comment: @Javaprogrammern00b I believe is not the same query